# Confused on some webBrowser functions

Tags: c#, multithreading, while-loop, webbrowser-control

```
public void PortalLogin()
        {
            string portalUrl = "URL";
            string portalEmail = "email";
            string portalPassword = "password";

            // Run when page finishes navigating
            webBrowser2.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                HtmlElement head = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
                HtmlElement testScript = webBrowser2.Document.CreateElement("script");
                IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)testScript.DomElement;
                element.text = "function PortalLogin() { document.getElementById('username').value = '" + portalEmail + "'; document.getElementById('password').value = '" + portalPassword + "';  document.getElementById('credentials').submit(); }";
                head.AppendChild(testScript);
                webBrowser2.Document.InvokeScript("PortalLogin");
            };

            // Navigate to the portal
            webBrowser2.Navigate(portalUrl);
            while (this.webBrowser2.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
```

I have the code segment above that is supposed to `Navigate` to a specific URL and then upon Navigate's completion, execute invoke a script to login to the webpage there.  Now, because the entire `PortalLogin()` function is inside of a while loop, I have to include the:

```
while (this.webBrowser2.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
```

segment so that the while loop doesn't just interrupt the Navigate function a ton.  However, the code isn't quite working, the flow seems to be off when I step through it with breakpoints.  I think part of the problem is I don't quite understand how the while loop testing `ReadState != Complete` works.  Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: Just remove that code, it does nothing useful.

Answer (score -2):

Better use WebClient with cookies or HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse.